Adding custom decorative shapes to Header and And Sections
I am trying to implementing the following header and section styles in latex but I am stuck.

I have tried implementing it using the fancyhdr and tikz packages. I was able to implement the line stretching from the document title, however I never managed to implement the rectangles correctly. They always either push the title and line below the rectangles or the are drawn over the header.
At this point I'm stumped. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to implement this header.
Update 1:
Here is the last latex code I settled on:
% Customizing the header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing the horizontal line
\fancypagestyle{customstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % Clear the header and footer
    \fancyhead[L]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        % Draw the box
        \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (1.5,0.6); % Box size and position
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{0.5em} % Space between the box and the section title
    \leftmark % Section title
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        % Draw the horizontal line
        \draw[thick] (1.5,0.3) -- (\textwidth,0.3); % Line from end of box to end of page
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Header line width
}

which produces the following header:


Hi there, welcome to StackExchange! You mention you've tried using tikz and fancyhdr so far. Would you be willing to edit your question to include your code in the format of a minimal working example? It'll be easier for others to help you if we have a starting point of what you already have :)

could you edit your code so it can be compiled to reproduce the output you show? that helps people to troubleshoot and try out fixes.

if you use remember picture, overlay, you need to leave space for them in the code you use to create the title, which you've not shown. otherwise, include the picture in the code for the title and set the title to the right of the rectangles. or typeset the title inside the picture. other possibilities. hard to say which would be simplest without knowing how you're producing the header.
